# js file not visible in Chrome Extension debugger

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a simple app that I'm using to learn Chrome Extensions.

I cannot get break points to work in mainscript.js file in the debugger.

I couldn't see mainscript.js under Pages or Content Scripts.
I can see it when I load Filesystem and apply breakpoints but they are not breaking. 
The alert is being displayed.

How do I set break points that work in mainscript.js?

Manifest:

```
{
   "name": "Enable/Disable",
   "version": "1.0",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "description": "Enables/Disables",

   "permissions": 
   [
     "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/*",
     "activeTab"
   ],

   "browser_action": 
   {
      "default_icon": 
      {
         "16": "images/Icon_ENABLED.png"
      }
   },

  "background": 
  {
     "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener
(
   function(tab) 
   {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "mainscript.js"});
   }
);
```

mainscript.js

```
alert('Mainscript');
```

Comment: After executeScript runs, the script should be displayed in the web page tab's devtools, sources panel, content scripts subpanel. If you want to pause immediately, simply add `debugger;` as the first  statement in the content script (editing it may require you to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page).

Comment: The debugger ignored the 'debugger;' command so didn't break.  So I didn't see the code in the Content scripts panel.
mainscript.js runs because I can see the alert.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how to run the debugger.
I open chrome://extensions/

I click on 'Inspect views background page'

I set breakpoints in background.js

I set breakpoints in mainscript.js (found under Filesystem)

I open a new tab with content in the browser e.g. BBC.com

I click my extension icon in that tab

Break points in background.js are hit but not in mainscript.js